# Can two identical strings not be equal to each other in Python?

Tags: python

Below is the code in question:

```
def search():
        name = enter.get()
        print(name)
        name = name.lower()
        data = open("moredata.txt")
        found = False
        results = str()

        for line in data:
            record = line.split("|")
            record[0] = str(record[0])
            print("'" + name + "'" "---" + "'" + record[0] + "'")

            if record[0] == name:
                found = True
                line = str(line)
                results += line
                results = str(results).lstrip(' ')

                continue
            else:
                found = False
                continue
        if not found:
            print("No results found")

        else:
            print("These items match your search query:\n")
            print(results)
            # print(results)
            print('\n---------------------------------\n')
```

In the text file I am using, pieces of information are separated by '|' and the function splits each piece into an array (I think?) and compares just the first value to what I put in the search bar.

I have used other text files with the same *exact* function, it works just fine: it verifies that the two strings are equal and then displays the entire line of the text file corresponding to what I wanted. However, when I search "a" which should register as equal to "a" from the line a|a|a|a|a|a in my text file, it doesn't. I know this is going to bite me later if I don't figure it out and move on because it works in some cases.

The line

```
print("'" + name + "'" "---" + "'" + record[0] + "'")
```

results in

```
'a'---'a'
'a'---'a'
'a'---'b'
```

when compared to lines

```
a|a|a|a|a|a
a|a|a|a|a|a
b|b|b|b|b|b
```

There are no empty lines between results, and both variable types are str().

Comment: `record` is a list of strings, so `record[0] = str(record[0])` is a no-op.

Comment: Try using `repr` when printing out a string for debugging. It will show any hidden characters.

Comment: Maybe after you find a matching line, you want to `break` out of the loop instead if continuing.

Comment: Those two `continue` statements are redundant. Do you mean a `break` in `if`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I've updated my code to be less redundant, but I will not be implementing `break` because I want the search to continue after finding the first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `continue` in your if statement in the loop is what's causing the problem as it should be a `break`.

Your program is finding it, but it's then being overwritten by the last iteration. Once your program has found, you should either never set `found` back to false, or preferably just cease the iteration altogether.

I would wager the other files you've tested with all end with the name that you were looking for, and this one is causing a problem because the name you're looking for isn't at the end.

Additionally, though technically not a problem, the other `continue` under the else in the for loop isn't necessary.

Comment: I want the function to find all entries that match, not just the first, which is why I chose "continue" over "break." By eliminating Found = False in the else statement, the issue went away. Thanks! However, even when the last entry was True, python counted it as False. So your advice helped and it works now, but I'm still confused -_-

Comment: Eliminating the else statement works because your `found` starts at False, and once at least one line is found, it becomes True, and it will stay that way even if nothing else matches again. Before hand, if something didn't match after it had matched, `found` would become False again, ignoring the fact that something had actually been found previously.

Answer (score 1):

Your `found` variable is being overwritten on each iteration of the loop.
Therefore it will only be `True` if the *last* result matches.

You don't actually need your `found` variable at all. If there are results, your `results` variable will have data in it and you can test for that.